# 9v + 2 LED set up. safe?

Tags: led

I have two 10mm white LEDs
 FW current is 20mA, FW supply is 3.5V typical or 4.0V Max.

I am wanting to connect them to one 9V battery I have a 100-ohm resistor at 1/4 watt 5% tolerance.

Is this a safe set up or do i need to change anything?
The 9V gets a little warm at the moment.

Comment: If the battery is getting warm with just a 20 mA current, either you're being too sensitive to its warmth, or something else is loading the battery. A standard 9 V battery doesn't really get heated up to any level of concern by even a 50-100 mA current draw.

Answer (score 2):

In series the LEDs will drop about 7V leaving 2V for the resistor. At 20mA this will be 100R. You could always reduce the current by using a higher value resistor - 200 = 10mA etc.